# How does the sklearn resample algorithm work for upsampling?

Tags: python, resample

can anybody explain, how the upsample procedure works? Are the new values only copies of the other values? I need an explanation for a presentation.
Thank you.

I read the docs, but there is not enough information to understand the algorithm.

> The default strategy implements one step of the bootstrapping procedure.

Comment: "Are the new values only copies of the other values?" --> seems like this would be verry easy to check with a simple and small monotonically increasing series